# Pyodbc query just returns one row

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyodbc

I just started using Pyodbc and I'm trying to run a query that I know that works perfectly using Sequel Pro. The query must return several rows, however, I can get just one.

Here is my query:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "select `T4`.`id`, `T4`.`r_id`, `structure`.`l2_id`, `structure`.`l2_name` from (select `T3`.`id`, `T3`.`r_id`, `item`.`L6_ID` from (select `T2`.`id`, `report`.`r_id` from (select `T1`.`id` from (select `entity`.`id` from `entity` where `entity`.`id` = %s) as `T1` inner join `coverage` on `T1`.`id` = `coverage`.`id`) as `T2` inner join `report` on `T2`.`id` = `report`.`id`) as `T3` inner join `item` on `T3`.`r_id` = `item`.`r_id`) as `T4` inner join `structure` on `T4`.`l6_id` = `structure`.`l6_id`"

 cursor.execute(sql, ('id1',))
 result = cursor.fetchone()
 for row in result:
   print(row[0])
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetchone() fetches a single row. You probably want to use fetchall() instead. For example:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this perhaps:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

or

```
result = cursor.fetchmany()
```

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchmany.html